# How to conditionally join dataframes with tidyverse?

Tags: r, join, dplyr, left-join

I am interested in how much treatment (in hours) a person received at the beginning of each care continuum (a person may have multiple care contiuums). How to conditionally join these two data frames following the two following conditions:

1. treatment had to be received after continuum start for that person (or on the same day) (basically treatment_date >= continuum_date)
2. output should only include received treatment hours received at first appointment for each person's continuum (basically min(treatment_date-continuum_date)).

**Persons' dataframe**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

persons = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ziygvwnbvq73fc/persons.csv?dl=1") %>% 
  mutate(continuum_start = ymd(continuum_start)) %>% 
  select(-1)
persons
```

[image]

**Treatments' dataframe**

```
treatments = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nfokiheo43lwjy/treatments.csv?dl=1") %>% 
  mutate(treatment_date = ymd(treatment_date)) %>% 
  select(-1)

treatments
```

[image]

Comment: Your second bullet doesn't make sense to me. What is your expected output for (say) `ID17`? (I chose that id since it has multiple starts.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this (or this is a good start, at least):

Assuming that `id, continuum_start` is perfectly unique in `persons`:

```r
persons %>%
  left_join(treatments, join_by(id, continuum_start <= treatment_date)) %>%
  summarize(received_hours = sum(received_hours), .by = c(id, continuum_start)) %>%
  head()
#       id continuum_start received_hours
# 1 ID1171      2011-10-14            1.0
# 2 ID1171      2013-11-22             NA
# 3   ID17      2010-02-16            3.0
# 4   ID17      2010-11-23            2.0
# 5 ID1448      2019-12-17             NA
# 6 ID1448      2018-01-04            5.5
```

If there may be multiple instances of the same `id, continuum_start` in `persons`, then we can work around that by pre-adding `mutate(rn = row_number())` before the join, then adding `rn` to the by-fields in summarize, ala `.by = c(rn, id, continuum_start)`.